# Delay in piping arecord output and into aplay

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe, alsa, netcat

There is a noticeable delay in the sound coming from the speakers when doing,

```
arecord | aplay
```

I want to reduce the latency because I want to write a low-latecy sound server with a bash script.

```
arecord {parameters} | nc    {parameters}   --> in first host
nc      {parameters} | aplay {parameters}   --> in second host
```

Is there a way in which I can reduce the latency? Or is it possible to write a low-latency sound server with a bash script?

Comment: to lower the latency, how about checking the cmdline flags of `arecord` and `aplay` (but don't forget that the two utlities are not written for low-latency *at all*)? in any case, such a naive implementation of an network audio connection will most likely not make you happy (unless this is purely for recreational purposes). e.g. do your hosts have the same hw clock to sync the audio streams on the soundcards? why not use something like `jacktrip`?

Answer (score 1):

Netcat (nc) is difficult to make work correctly as you really need to use the UDP protocol instead of TCP.  TCP will always exhibit lag, and that lag will get worse over time. The reason is because as soon as a packet is dropped, TCP will try to auto recover the packet, thus introducing more lag delay in real-time transmissions.  On the other hand, UDP will ignore dropped packets, keeping your real-time interface current.  On Wi-Fi, dropped packets are common, so this issue is very noticeable.

[GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is pretty easy to get working over UDP.  I'm sure there's a way to get gstreamer to work with arecord and aplay, but there's really no need as gstreamer supports [ALSA](https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page) directly.   Example:

Microphone on client (192.168.44.10)  Transmitting to remote host (192.168.44.1):

```
 $ gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc device=hw:2,0 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=192.168.44.1 port=5002
```

Server host (192.168.44.1) {receiver}  Speakers:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5002 caps=application/x-rtp ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink device=hw:1,0
```

Use "aplay -l" to determine the hardware device number of your sound card(s).  For instance this is the output on my server host, which has the speakers attached:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: Device [Generic USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--buffer-size=0
```

for both arecord and aplay works for me.

Comment: Hello. I tried `--buffer-size=0` and was still getting the same delay as without the flag. But then I tried changing `0` to `1` (which is 1 millisecond), and it removed the perceived delay. Seems like `arecord` and `aplay` treated `0` as if the buffer size is not set, which causes them to buffer up to 500 ms per their manual pages. May it be an implementation discrepancy? My `arecord` and `aplay` are version 1.2.5.1 by Jaroslav Kysela.

Comment: Also, trying `aplay` pipe with `netcat` gives me a "read error".